# How to safely get the a particular base type of a control?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a user control A which inherits from a concrete base type B which in turn inherits from a generic control C.

I need to check if A inherits from C and currently I'm doing the following:

```
var cType = typeof(C<>);
var aType = typeof(A);

if (aType.BaseType.BaseType?.Name == cTye.Name) {}
```

or

```
if (aType.BaseType.BaseType?.GetType() == cTye.GetType()) {}
```

The above works but I was wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [is-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is).